# Microphone input stops working after 10-20 minutes within Discord/Google Meet etc…in Windows 11

Tags: google-chrome, audio, microphone, discord, google-meet

I am using a high-spec Windows 11 PC with all the latest patches. I am using chat apps like Google Meet.

When talking to friends on Google Meet I seem to have an issue where the microphone input works absolutely fine for 10–20 minutes and then it just stops working and I have to refresh the Google Chrome tab and the sound works fine again for 10–20 mins. This is a wired microphone and works perfectly fine using chat apps on my Linux machine, so I know this is something related to my Windows 11 setup.

It appears to happen in Discord—the actual application, so it is something appears to be systemwide and not just in Chrome.

How should I start to best debug this issue? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using Firefox? If it works, that would suggest there's some setting in Chrome that needs to be adjusted. [Google Meet and the rest of G Workspace are working better than ever on Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/en/products/firefox/google-meet-firefox/). Oh, hang on... you said Discord in the title... can you simply try recording from the microphone and see if it still stops after 10-20 mins?

Comment: It appears to happen in Discord the actual application so it is something appears to be systemwide and not just in Chrome

Comment: Is it a USB microphone? If so, can you find any power settings for it? (I'm only coming up with random ideas here.)

Comment: If it's surely system-wide, not sure why you tagged 2 random apps instead of Windows. What microphone is it? Are you testing on the same machine (to eliminate USB port or other hardware issues)?

Comment: I'd still check using a different (**not chromium based**) browser, since *"Discord - the actual application"* is simply an Electron app, which, you may not know, uses Chromium as a web client - so, the fact that it behaves the same as Chrome is not surprising, since it's based on the same garbage core

Comment: It is a HYPERX Cloud II Pro 7.1 Gaming Headset plugged in via USB -  it seems fine with my Linux machine with all chat apps in Chrome, just for some reason it seems to stop working on the windows machine i'll try to debug it more and get more info